# how to use jenkins and devops for .net and python development work

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli, web2py-modules

We are initial stage of bringing devops into our daily activities. Now we are workig on .net and pthon coding. So we have to plan for continuous delivery on our activities.

In the first scenario for python development works, we are using web2py now. So developers can directly access the python files and work and test their webdevelopment work by web2py with certain port.
How jenkins can help here to automate this process and developers should get a easy GUI or way to test or compile their codes before it got deployed o web2py.

Also we need to automate the build activity of .net code as well. What are the best possible ways

Comment: Any guidance please?